# How can I open an .xls file as a separate process

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

How can I open an .xls file as a separate process in Excel from application written in Qt Creator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please rephrase the question to ask a specific question. For eg. how to use a specific function in a C++ library that provides support for loading/opening excel files. The statement "an application written in QtCreator" is not very encouraging either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QDesktopServices::[openUrl](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl)

`QDesktopServices::openUrl`(QUrl("file:///C:/file.xls", QUrl::TolerantMode));

> If the URL is a reference to a local file (i.e., the URL scheme is
>   "file") then it will be opened with a suitable application instead of
>   a Web browser.